# Pianobar Mutes/Stalls other audio on Linux [void linux]

Tags: linux, audio

So I've been having this problem since I installed the software. Pianobar will, for example, let notification sounds queue up until the application is closed. YouTube videos will not play with it open, but resume the moment it is closed -- as if it was hanging while waiting for access to the audio. It seems as if it's locking the audio so only it can play and I'm not sure how to fix it. If anybody knows how I can fix this so that it play in parallel to other sounds, it would be greatly appreciated.

Additionally, I noticed no activity on the "Desktop Output" channel of OBS with Pianobar open, but other sounds were shown correctly (after quitting it, of course.)

Edit: Additionally, I get this error while trying to start pianobar over a separate audio source

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1099:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ao_alsa ERROR: Unable to open ALSA device 'default' for playback => Device or resource busy
/!\ Cannot open audio device.
```

Comment: Maybe try OSS instead of ALSA?

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate if you are only running ALSA, or also Pulseaudio.

Answer (score 1):

When a program uses the ALSA driver directly, it takes over the entire sound card. Most distros include another driver on top of ALSA to allow several connections at once. Since you're running Void Linux, I'm pretty sure pianobar should be using PulseAudio rather than ALSA or OSS. Try adding "default_driver=pulse" to the end of /etc/libao.conf. If PulseAudio is not installed, you can find instructions [here](https://wiki.voidlinux.eu/PulseAudio).

Sources:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=158070

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pianobar

(For some reason I find the Arch Linux community to be very helpful when it comes to random audio problems)

Comment: I went ahead and followed these instructions, only to get the same error. Unfortunately, it still takes over the full audio. Why is pianobar still trying to use ALSA when it's not even in my services any more? Other applications are doing simultaneous playback just fine when it's closed (tested with Firefox, VLC, Telegram.)

Comment: Okay, I'd like to report that I SOLVED the problem. Apparently, what I needed was to install the `libao-pulse` package. Once I installed that everything worked correctly.